# Looking for generalisation of the `if p x then x else empty` construct

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, alternative-functor

I have a couple of snippets which feel like they're doing the same thing, but I'm not entirely convinced there is a generalised construct to handle them both. In one place, I have

```
ensure :: (String -> Bool) -> String -> String
ensure p x =
    if p x then
        x
    else
        ""
```

This might in use look something like

```
ensure (/= "kim") "alex"    -- returns "alex"
ensure (/= "kim") "kim"     -- returns ""
```

in another, I have the very similar

```
ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
ensure p maybeX = do
    x <- maybeX
    if p x then
        Just x
    else
        Nothing
```

This would instead look something like

```
ensure even 6     -- returns Just 6
ensure even 11    -- returns Nothing
```

Both are checking whether a value is correct according to some predicate, and if it's not they're returning a default "empty"-looking value. There is a slight difference though – which means the second function could be rewritten as

```
ensure :: (Maybe a -> Bool) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
ensure p maybeX =
    if p x then
        x
    else
        Nothing
```

to make them more similar, putting the responsibility of "unwrapping" the `Maybe` on the predicate. With this new definition, both functions would fall under

```
ensure :: Alternative f => (f a -> Bool) -> f a -> f a
ensure p x =
    bool x empty (p x)
```

So, my question is,

**Does this `bool x empty (p x)` exist in some form so I don't have to implement this function myself?** The problem with inlining `bool x empty (p x)` is that in my case, both `p` and `x` are quite long.

Comment: I would define `ensure` as `ensure :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a; ensure p = mfilter p . return`.

Comment: `ensure` reminds me of [`guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) but looks much more useful

Comment: Your second form looks like [`mfilter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mfilter). Passing an unwrapped value to the predicate seems to be better.

Comment: @user3237465 I have an almost identical definition in `Dmwit.Prelude`, namely, `ensure p x = x <$ guard (p x)`.

Comment: @user3237465 ...and then chain it with fromMaybe to get an empty string when run as `ensure (/= "kim") "kim"`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The smallest requirement set I can think of: `ensure (Eq a, Monoid a) => (a -> Bool) -> a -> a; ensure p = if p a then a else mempty`. This could even work work for numbers if we decided under which operation we are using the monoid.

Comment: 9000: I think your `Eq` requirement is superfluous

Comment: @kqr, you can, but I would define two versions of `ensure`: one for `Monoid` and one for `MonadPlus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are suggestions from the comments. One using `Monoid`, by [9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223424/9000):

```
ensure :: Monoid a => (a -> Bool) -> a -> a
ensure p a = if p a then a else mempty
```

Another using `MonadPlus`, by [user3237465](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3237465/user3237465):

```
ensure :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a
ensure p = mfilter p . return
```

And a variant of the second one that only requires `Alternative`, by [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791604/daniel-wagner):

```
ensure :: Alternative f => (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
ensure p x = x <$ guard (p x)
```